# problems getting the values of a select element-

Tags: javascript, dom, facebook

struggling to get the value of a selected item

html-

```
<select name="recommendFriend" onChange="friendWall(127);return false;" id="recommendFriend">



var user = document.getElementById("recommendFriend").getAttribute("value")
```

im using JS on facebook

Answer (score 0):

Select boxes are a bit tougher to get the value of...

```
 document.nameOfForm.idOfSelect.options[document.nameOfForm.idOfSelect.selectedIndex].value
```

should get you where you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

`<select />` tags have no `value` attribute. Instead, you should use the [`selectedIndex` or the `value`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html) *property*.

```
var selectElem = document.getElementById("recommendFriend");
var user = selectElem.value;
```

I can't remember if all modern browsers support the `value` property (I'm pretty certain they do), but if not, then do this:

```
var selectElem = document.getElementById("recommendFriend");
var selectedIndex = selectElem.selectedIndex;
var user = selectElem.options[selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: i keep getting undefined for the user variable- facebook doesnt like the second solution- the selectedIndex is the probleem for some reason

Comment: Some old browsers didn't support `value` on select; selectedIndex is the traditional safe way. @chris: I don't think you're picking up the right element. Check the source for other elements having the same `id="recommendFriend"` attribute (this is invalid).

Comment: (And incidentally, don't use `getAttribute` on an HTML DOM, as IE has many bugs with it. Use the direct DOM Level 1 HTML properties like `value` in this case. On form elements, the HTML `value` attribute is the initial value; the current value which you want to read may be different.)

Comment: searched the document for recommendFriend only one occurence-  im using chrome and FF

Comment: do `alert(selectElem.tagName)`. If it's correctly `select`, you should have no problem reading the `value` or `selectedIndex`. If it's something else, that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have found the problem- yet again facebook has its own ideas about JS- the solution was

```
var selectElem = document.getElementById("recommendFriend");
var user = selectElem.getValue()
```